# how to save form data to database in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajaxform

I am pretty new in angular.
I'm working on an internal tool where I can get the user details like location, work profile and mobile number etc.
So i have a form with location, work profile dropdowns and mobile number input field. Here for the above fields im already getting data from database through ajax get request. If i want to change data like mobileNumber, how can i do that and how to save that to database which should override the before mobile number. thanks in advance.

here is my html code:

```
 <form name="userForm">
                    <div class="page-heading fs-xs-1-5">
                       Update Profile
                    </div>
                    <div class= "second-row">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="Location"> Location</label>
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="location" ng-model="user.location" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Location</option>
                                    <option>Hyderabad</option>
                                    <option>Ahmadabad</option>
                                    <option>New Jersey</option>
                                    <option>California</option>
                                    <option>Jaipur</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="WorkProfile"> Work Profile</label>
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="workprofile" ng-model="user.workProfile" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Profile</option>
                                    <option>UI Developer</option>
                                    <option>Tester</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <label for="ContactNumber"> Contact Number</label>
                            <input class="form-width contact-height" type="text" ng-model="user.mobileNumber" maxlength="20" required></input>
                        </div>
                      </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="third-row">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label for="SkillSet"> Skill Set</label>
                        <textarea id="SkillSet" class="form-width" placeholder="Enter Your skill set here..." row="4" col="100" ng-model="user.skillset" maxlength="250" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>        
                    <button class="btn btn-primary setng-btn" type="submit" ng-click="addnewdata">Save</button>
                    </form>
```

js:`

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('app.login')
        .factory('userprofileService', userprofileService);

    userprofileService.$inject = ['config', '$http'];

    function userprofileService (config, $http) {
        var userprofileService = this;
        userprofileService.getUserDetails = function(){
        return $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: config.apiURL+'/v2/user',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    }).then(function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    });
        }
`
```

Comment: You send a PUT request to your backend, with the data that needs to be changed, and the backend updates the database.

Comment: The [ng-click directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) on the submit button needs to invoke a function `addnewdata()`, not just name the function.

Answer (score -1):

That will be too much to make clear.
for short, you need REST service as backend to call to save data.

AngularJS project is only front-end, you need backend ( to develop with Nodejs, JSP or asp.net/C# ) to serve this purpose.

Comment: Actually we are using a api here, so i need to post the data to that api and in the backend api will save the latest data to database. but here im not able to post data to api, can you help me that. thanks in advance.